# Transfer old email messages to new server

Tags: email

Novice in the tech aspects of email servers here:

**Situation**: We have an old hosting (and mail) provider that we're moving away from. They are using Mail Enable Enterprise (it's a microsoft server in case it matters and they don't have cPanel). They have 7 GB of our email messages on their server, we also have those messsages downloaded to a machine via IMAP.

**We need to:** transfer these messages to a new server / provider. I went ahead and asked HostGator tech.support and they are unable to do the import so I am looking for a different provider who can import the messages (and folders) and then just be a good email provider.

**Question:** Could you suggest a provider (does Google Apps do that?) that let's me import / upload messages to their server OR maybe suggest another way of solving this.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This is a site for programming questions, not general software or computer support. Please take a few minutes to read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq), which has information about what types of questions are appropriate to ask here. Unfortunately, this one is not; voting to close it as off-topic. We try very hard to keep things here on-topic, as it helps StackOverflow remain a valuable programming resource. :-)

Comment: OMG sorry about the offtopic part.. I'm lame. I go to SO everytime I have a computer question and most of the time its programming so I made it a habit and forgot there are other sites:)

but again unless there needs to be a script written to transfer emails! :) looks like that's not the case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you have IMAP on both sides, right?

Drag'n'drop in your email client will work just fine.  Yes, it's a lot of data, and it might take a bit, but it's the simplest thing that might possibly work.  It's hard to go wrong with simple things.

There's also [imapsync](http://imapsync.lamiral.info/), but then you'll need to already know the login information on both sides, which is something you might not have for every account on the old server.

Comment: This question is off-topic (there is absolutely nothing programming-related involved), and instead of answering it you should be helping migrate it to an appropriate SE site.

Comment: @KenWhite, funny, I thought I did.  Apparently between the time that I edited the question and I answered it, I also thought that I voted to migrate.  Apparently someone else placed that first vote and I totally spaced on the fact that it wasn't me.  Probably you?  Regardless, yes, this is very much off topic here on SO.

Comment: It's usually not a good idea to post an answer to an off-topic question (even if you vote to migrate/close it), because it encourages others to post off-topic questions as well. (I know it's off-topic, but somebody might answer it before it gets closed, so I'll post it anyway.) You should probably delete your answer for that reason. :-)

Comment: And give up possible rep on the other sites?  Pfah!  ;)

Comment: :-) Would you prefer to lose it here? I can help a little. <g>